# How to handle seg faults under Windows?

Tags: windows, fault

How can a Windows application handle segmentation faults? By 'handle' I mean intercept them and perhaps output a descriptive message. Also, the ability to recover from them would be nice too, but I assume that is too complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SEH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28VS.85%29.aspx) for early exception handling, 
and use [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634%28VS.85%29.aspx) to show a descriptive message.

Comment: Do the __try and __except blocks work with other Windows compilers like mingw32? (Not just vc++)

Comment: You can go down this route (though I'd encourage you to check out what WER can do for you, you *can* register to get the reports / provide problem links!) - remember that your app will be in a very hosed state in the filter, you will be pretty limited as to what you can safely do ; anything involving new/delete is out for example.

Comment: I guess I'll stick with VC++ then.

Comment: After learned what WER is, it's really convenient to handle application crash. I also recommend WER now. But when tried the sample of WER is not support Windows XP.

Comment: Check out libSEH for (MINGW32, CYGWIN) http://www.programmingunlimited.net/siteexec/content.cgi?page=libseh
  and  
http://www.programmingunlimited.net/siteexec/content.cgi?page=mingw-seh

Answer (score 5):

Let them crash and let the Windows Error Reporting handle it - under Vista+, you should also consider registering with Restart Manager (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373347(VS.85).aspx), so that you have a chance to save out the user's work and restart the application (like what Word/Excel/etc.. does)

Answer (score 3):

If you add the `/EHa` compiler argument then `try {} catch(...)` will catch all exceptions for you, including SEH exceptions.
You can also use `__try {} __except {}` which gives you more flexibility on what to do when an exception is caught. putting an `__try {} __except {}` on your entire `main()` function is somewhat equivalent to using `SetUnhandeledExceptionFilter()`.

That being said, you should also use the proper terminology: "seg-fault" is a UNIX term. There are no segmentation faults on Windows. On Windows they are called "Access Violation Exceptions"

Comment: One warning: enabling /EHa is a recipe for introducing security vulnerabililities in your application.  The problem is that there are exceptions that are thrown by the operating system (like guard page exceptions) which can correctly be filtered if you use the __except filter but if you use /EHa and try {} catch() you won't be able to determine if it's appropriate to let the OS handle the exception.  Structured exceptions are extremely difficult to get right without introducing security defects, IMHO Paul Betts answer is right - let the OS handle the error.

Comment: I thought I had explained the issue above.  Masking exceptions like guard page exceptions or random memory access errors can introduce security holes (for instance if you catch memory access errors, an attacker can use this to defeat platform protections like ASLR - there was at least one recent MSFT security bulletin that was caused by this issue).

Comment: Apologies for the drive-by down vote.  Accidental mis-click and then didn't discover my vote before it was locked.

Comment: SEH exception handling is not a black box.   If the error code is well known... and is something you can ignore... you can handle them.   __try, __except is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

C++ self-contained example on how to use `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`, triggering a write fault and displaying a nice error message:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>

LONG WINAPI TopLevelExceptionHandler(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExceptionInfo)
{
  std::stringstream s;
  s << "Fatal: Unhandled exception 0x" << std::hex << pExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode 
  << std::endl;

  MessageBoxA(NULL, s.str().c_str(), "my application", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
  exit(1);

  return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

int main()
{
   SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(TopLevelExceptionHandler);
   int *v=0;
   v[12] = 0;   // should trigger the fault
   return 0;
}
```

Tested successfully with `g++` (and should work OK with MSVC++ as well)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here depends on what sort of faults you are concerned with. If you have sloppy code that is prone to more or less random General Protection Violations, then @Paul Betts answer is what you need.

If you have code that has a good reason to deference bad pointers, and you want to recover, start from @whunmr's suggestion about SEH. You can handle and indeed recover, if you have clear enough control of your code to know exactly what state it is in at the point of the fault and how to go about recovering.

Comment: I hope my code isn't sloppy :) Most of the faults in my app come from the embeded python interpreter. Certain scripts seem to cause problems.

Comment: If you throw away and recreate the interpreter, and if that process does not leak, then you're good to go.

Comment: Too bad that isn't an option.

Comment: Put python in its own process and communicate via pipes or files?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jean-François Fabre solution, but with Posix code in MinGW-w64.  But note that the program must exit - it can't recover from the SIGSEGV and continue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sigHandler(int s)
{
    printf("signal %d\n", s);
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, sigHandler);
    int *v=0;
    *v = 0;   // trigger the fault

    return 0; 
}
```